# Multiple relational tables to nested JSON format using Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested

I'm trying to create nested JSON object by combining more than one relational tables using python/pandas. I'm a beginner in Python/pandas, so looking for bit of a help here...

In the following example, instead of tables, I'm using CSV files just to keep it simple

> #### *Table1.csv*
>
> Emp_id, Gender, Age
>   1, M, 32
>   2, M, 35
>   3, F, 31
>
> #### *Table2.csv*
>
> Emp_id, Month, Incentive
>   1, Aug, 3000
>   1, Sep, 3500
>   1, Oct, 2000
>   2, Aug, 1500
>   3, Aug, 5000
>   3, Sep, 2400

I want to create a JSON object like below

> #### *Required output:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "employee": 1,
        "gender": M,
        "age": 32,
        "incentive": [{
            "aug": 3000,
            "sep": 3500,
            "oct": 2000
        }],
        "employee": 2,
        "gender": M,
        "age": 35,
        "incentive": [{
            "aug": 1500
        }],
        "employee": 3,
        "gender": F,
        "age": 31,
        "incentive": [{
            "aug": 5000,
            "sep": 2400
        }]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join first, then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with lambda function for dictionaries and convert [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html), last add top `key` value and convert to `json`:

```
d = (df1.merge(df2, on='Emp_id', how='left')
         .groupby(['Emp_id','Gender','Age'])['Month','Incentive']
         .apply(lambda x: [dict(x.values)])
         .reset_index(name='Incentive')
         .to_dict(orient='records')

)
#print (d)

import json
json = json.dumps({'data':d})
```

---

```
print (json)

{
    "data": [{
        "Emp_id": 1,
        "Gender": "M",
        "Age": 32,
        "Incentive": [{
            "Aug": 3000,
            "Sep": 3500,
            "Oct": 2000
        }]
    }, {
        "Emp_id": 2,
        "Gender": "M",
        "Age": 35,
        "Incentive": [{
            "Aug": 1500
        }]
    }, {
        "Emp_id": 3,
        "Gender": "F",
        "Age": 31,
        "Incentive": [{
            "Aug": 5000,
            "Sep": 2400
        }]
    }]
}
```